# Cannot pass one variable value from one function to the other function

Tags: python, python-2.7

In my code, after declaring the global variable prime, it should take the values from the first and add to the second and after executing I should get an array like [1, 2, 3, 7]. But when I am printing the second function I am getting only [3, 7]. Any idea where I am wrong? Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np 

prime = []  
nprime = []


def first():
    global prime
    global nprime
    prime = np.append(1, 2)
    nprime = np.append(6, 4)
    return (prime, nprime)


def second():
    global prime
    prime = np.append(3, 7)
    return prime


A = second()
print A
```

Comment: For one, your sample code doesn't call `first`

Comment: why are you using `np.append()` ?

Comment: but do I even have to call the first function? I made the array global. @AnthonySottile

Comment: If you want the code which puts 1 and 2 into your array to run (the code in `first`) you'll need to run that code by calling `first()`

Comment: (That said, even if you do that, you throw away the value of `prime` by assigning into it `prime = np.append(3, 7)`)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you do call `first()` in your program, the issue occurs becaue when you do -

```
np.append(3,7)
```

You are creating a new list - `[3,7]` - and assigning it to `prime` variable. This does not append to the existing prime.

I am not even sure why you are using `np.append()` , if you want to append a single value to simple list, use `list.append()`, if you want to append multiple values to a simple list use `list.extend()` . Example -

```
prime = []  
nprime = []


def first():
    global prime
    global nprime
    prime.extend([1, 2])
    nprime.extend([6, 4])
    return (prime, nprime)


def second():
    global prime
    prime.extend([3, 7])
    return prime

first()
A = second()
print A
```

---

That being said, using global variables is not really recommended , an easier way to do this for you would be to return the value from your first and pass it as argument to your second function, Example -

```
prime = []  
nprime = []


def first(prime, nprime):
    prime.extend([1, 2])
    nprime.extend([6, 4])
    return (prime, nprime)


def second(prime):
    prime.extend([3, 7])
    return prime

prime, nprime = first(prime)
prime = second(prime)
print prime
```

This is a very simplified example, not sure what you want to do with this.